# what is the format for saving a qml QVariantList<QVariant> in qml file so it can be bindable in qml when loading the file?

Tags: qml, qvariant

i am doing an application and i need to save the QVariantList list in a qml file so i can load it in qml every time i start the application

to make it more clear i read qpoints from qml and store them in a qvariantlist in c++ so the next step is to save it in text file i use the format(that's how i write it to file.qml)

```
import ARHandbook 1.0;
x:["1 2" , "1 3"]
```

but it doesnt load in qml so what is the right format to store it with ?
it gives this error  unable to assin qvariantlist to void

Answer (score 2):

For QtQuick 1.x, you should use property variant type, from QtQuick 2.0, you can just use property var to store array types.

See 
http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/5.0/qml-var.html and  http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qml-variant.html for details.